# AEM is fails for the Video upload alone but works for images able to see Granite JS fails

Tags: aem

03.03.2024 21:45:06.675 *ERROR* [10.178.68.215 [1709502306670] POST /content/dam/myassets/testfine.createasset.html HTTP/1.1]
org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver
Calling the error handler resulted in an error
org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException:

Comment: Hi, please add more information: is this a new setup locally? what AEM version is running? is it an existent environment? does it happens for all videos or only after certain size? Also, the stack trace is incomplete, it is hard to tell what could be happening.